# How to download Spring and Hibernate JARs through Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, buildship

I'm currently using Eclipse with Buildship plugin. I want to download Spring and Hibernate JARs into my gradle project, how do I do this? I placed the following in my build.gradle file for dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.6.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    jcentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'one.MainClass'
    }
}
```

Upon running gradle build, it says that the build is successful, and I can run the JAR file produced. I cannot however, find the Spring JARs.

How can I download the Spring jars into my eclipse project so i can add them to the build path?

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple questions here: 1) Where does gradle put the jars that it downloads (i.e. where is the gradle jar cache located)? and 2) How do you set up a gradle project in Eclipse, such that the jars referenced in build.gradle are available on the Eclipse classpath?

Comment: Yes, exactly. What I need is indeed the answer to these two questions.

Comment: Found out that Gradle places the Spring JARs in (C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework). I guess I just need to move these files into my eclipse project then include them in my path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Eclipse plugin for Gradle, Gradle can handle adding jars to the Eclipse path for you:

```
allprojects{
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
}
```

After you include that in your build script, simply run `gradle eclipse` and it will generate the `.settings` directory and the `.project` and `.classpath` files typical of Eclipse projects, replacing them if they already exist.  Run this task and refresh your project in Eclipse anytime you change dependencies.

Alternatively, there is a Gradle plugin for Eclipse in the marketplace that can handle this, so long as you import your project as a gradle project.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where the jars are that you want, then do:

**Right-click on project -> Build path -> Configure build path... -> Libraries (tab) -> Add External JARs...**

Then select all the jars you want from C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1...